# How to start beaglebone black without OS?

Tags: embedded, beagleboard, beagleboneblack

I got a beaglebone black version and downloaded the starterware for example code. I can build .bin file but I have no idea how to make it work in the board. I put the MLO and modify 'gpioLedBlink.bin' name to 'app' and put them into SD card. Open the power, I know beaglebone didn't get into the original linux, but it only open USER LED 012, but there no led blink. I think the program didn't really work.

How should I solve this problem? And how can I use gdb to debug the program?

Another question is that there is no ttyUSB* when I plug the usb. How should I get the linux information when beagle black get into the original linux. THX.=)

Comment: dying to hear the answer to this question.  the beaglebone is pretty easy to use bare metal.  my beaglebone black is collecting dust because it boots differently and is less friendly, I gave up trying...

Comment: are you getting it to boot uboot?

Comment: This sure looks like an attempt at building a simple binary, without either linux or u-boot.

Answer (score 0):

Use Uboot and loady to load your binary over serial (default address is 0x8020 0000). Once it has loaded, go 0x80200000.

GL.